# Maxing out shmpages

Tags: mysql, optimization, mediatemple

We've got a Media Temple dv install (running dv 3.5) that keeps hitting its hard limit. Currently, it's using 68,124 of 68950 hard limit.

They've been less than helpful in helping us diagnosing this, other than copying and pasting some answers and links to things in their KnowledgeBase.

Any ideas on how to diagnose this further?

I've already run `mysqltuner.pl` and have been able to Google and fix a few things in there, but it's not really having much effect. I also ran `mysqlcheck -or -A -u` and that got rid of some fragmented tables, but obviously isn't the culprit either.

Any ideas or other things I can try to diagnose and/or optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if you feel that support at (mt) has not been helpful. I have found your account and Support Request, and the information there is accurate. If you have already optimized & tuned MySQL as much as possible & don't have any intense or extremely frequent requests, upgrading to the 64-bit OS will help. The (dv) Dedicated-Virtual Server 4.0's have higher kernel limits than the (dv) 3.5's. -(mt) Sara